# Angular: how to switch routes based on function calls

Tags: angularjs, routes, onbeforeunload

I have three routes in my `app.js` but when i am switching from create to any other route i want to check whether the user has intentionally click to switch or is it a mistake so there will be return popup that will ask user to stay on the page or leave the page. In usual cases it would have worked with this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
}
```

but since this is a SPA application i have to run this function while switching the routes:

**HERE IS MY ROUTES**

```
testApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/tests', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/tests/:testsId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      }).
      when('/create/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
        controller: 'CreateCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/tests'
      });
  }]);
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to this with an angular directive :

```
.directive('confirm', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AEC',
            link: function($scope, element) {
                element.bind('click', function(event) {

                        if (!confirm('You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?')) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

and in your HTML :

```
<a href="/route" confirm>link</a>
```

This way the standard link redirection will get intercepted and the redirection will only occur if user confirm it.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3119/

**edit:** removed jquery reference + jsfiddle link

**edit2:** for global redirection interception (like a backspace key or any clicked link on the page), see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9MnE9/124/

Here, I use `$routeChangeStart` to watch any location change.

Comment: what if somebody press "BACKSPACE" ??

Comment: When ? after redirection ? he will be redirected to previous page, like any other SPA/website, but you can choose not to by replacing location instead of adding a new route to location history (not part of your question)

Comment: no i am asking, i am on the create page and i pressed backspace i might have came from some other page so i will be redirected back to that page in this case this directive wont be triggered.

Comment: is there any way i can do it on backspace also ??

Comment: this still doesn't work for backspace, if somehow i can trigger your directive confirm on the document keydown event backspace then maybe it'll work.

Comment: sorry for that you're right. use `$routeChangeStart` instead of `$locationChangeStart` to enable the backspace to be working. Post edited and jsfiddle edited

Comment: now even if i say cancel it still goes back to the previous route.